# Is is possible to make additional fonts available only for one application?

Tags: fonts

I installed Carlito and Caladea via Ubuntu Software Center as a substitute for Calibri and Cambria and it works great! However, some applications (such as WPS office) do not recognize this substitution, so I installed Calibri and Cambria as well in /home/.fonts/. However, now Google Chrome and LibreOffice do not show some e-mails and text created in Calibri (text is not so clear to read when font size is less than 10px).

Is it possible to use substitution for LibreOffice and Chrome, while to install fonts just for WPS office?